# How can I modify -printf "%s \n" in find command to give me size in MB and not bytes?

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, printf

I am writing a simple helper function to show a sizes of the files: 
This is the code I have so far:

```
find . -type f -size +10M -printf "%f -> %s B\n"
```

The output I get is:

```
clay-banks--Ni2fpLUgRI-unsplash.jpg -> 181794593 B
jake-nackos-_kdX2vPc33U-unsplash.jpg -> 448148323 B
73-738467_nature-wallpapers-high-quality-images-hd-desktop-images.jpg -> 131115725 B
```

However, I want to show the file sizes in MB.

How should I modify this so it works like b

```
clay-banks--Ni2fpLUgRI-unsplash.jpg -> 173 MB
jake-nackos-_kdX2vPc33U-unsplash.jpg -> 427 MB
73-738467_nature-wallpapers-high-quality-images-hd-desktop-images.jpg -> 125 MB
```

Comment: Is the exact format crucial? do you always want MB or do you just want "human readable" multipliers KB / MB / GB ?

Comment: Yes, that should be the exact format - always MB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least on GNU-based systems, you should be able to use `stat` and `numfmt` to get the desired format, ex.:

```
find . -type f -size +10M -printf "%f -> " -exec sh -c '
  stat -c "%s" "$1" | numfmt --to-unit=1048576 --format="%.0f MB"
' sh {} \;
```

Change `--to-unit=1048576` to `--to-unit=1000000` depending whether you want MB or MiB.

Comment: `--to-unit=1Mi` instead of `--to-unit=1048576`

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the ast-open implementation of `ls`:

```
find . -type f -size +10M -exec ls -ldh --format='%(name)s -> %(size)dB' {} +
```

Would use `MiB`, `GiB`, `TiB`... suffixes as appropriate.

With `zsh`, on any system (using builtin functions only), for MiB only (rounded to nearest):

```
zmodload zsh/stat
stat -LnA info +size -- **/*(D.LM+10)
for f s ($info) printf '%s -> %.0fMiB\n' $f $(($s / 1048565.))
```

Answer (score 0):

The race is over and @steeldriver won *+1 ;-)*, but I would have gone a different (maybe simpler ?) way:

```
$ find . -type f -size +10M -printf "%f\0%s\n" | awk -F'\0' '{printf("%s -> %.0f MB\n", $1,$2/1048576)}'
```

Comment: This is nice, but it will fail for a file with spaces.

Comment: This won't: `find . -type f -size +10M -printf "%f\0%s\n" | awk -F'\0' '{printf("%s -> %.0f MB\n", $1,$2/1048576)}'`

Comment: @BrunoSaboia that'll still fail for a file with newline(s) in the name

Comment: It doesn't really fails, it only displays it weird:

 -> 0 MB
a -> 0 MB
b -> 0 MB
 -> 11 MB

This file, `\na\nb\n\` has the correct size displayed at the last line.

Feel free to correct, I think that this is a super edge case anyway.

Comment: @BrunoSaboia: this is actually the definition of "to fail for ..." no matter whether one thinks of spaces of new lines or something else...